# Need to solve an if/else and "and" problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just trying to get python to be able to tell if two functions I've made a and b both have the string "John" in it, but it's not working

I've tried using elif (example: 'elif "John" not in a and b' instead of the "else" there) but that didn't make a difference. I tried removing Jack from b and only leaving the quotation marks, that actually returns "Only one of them are named John", this is correct of course because when I change it to just the quotation marks, b does not say "John", but b does not say john when the string is "Jack" either, then why does it not say "Only one of them are named John" when I put "Jack" there? (sorry for my bad punctuation use, I'm very bad at it)

Here's the code for you to look at:

```
    a = "John"
    b = "Jack"

    if "John" in a and b:
        print("Both are named John")
    else:
        print("Only one of them are named John")
```

I expected the result to say "Only one of them are named John" when b didn't have the string "John", but it always says "Both are named John"

Comment: Note that the `else` case could also be that none of `a` and `b` are called John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `if "John" in a and b:` which meant `if ("John" in a) and b:`

This is because **`in` has higher precedence than `or`**.

You need to do this:

```
a = "John"
b = "Jack"

if "John" in a and "John" in b:
    print("Both are named John")
else:
    print("Only one of them are named John")
```

Pay attention to `if "John" in a and "John" in b:` which is equivalent to `if ("John" in a) and ("John" in b):`

Comment: omg! now that you actually point it out, I realized how simple it was ugh! I'm so stupid lol. Thank you so much for the help dude, really appreciate it!

Comment: I upvoted it, but it won't let me accept it until 7 minutes have passed :(